# Erlang: oom inside docker container

Tags: docker, erlang, elixir, out-of-memory, cgroups

I run `Erlang 22.4` vm inside docker container with such opts:

```
ERL_OPTS="+MMsco true +Musac true"
```

I assumed this flag told to erlang vm to respect containers cgroup limits inside which it runs. But I proceed to catch oom's periodically.

```
Container exited with status 137
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you just running `erl` command inside the container or any erlang application?

Comment: Are you sure you're providing enough free memory for the VM? Giving it a bit more headroom will likely solve your issue.

Comment: @VenkatakumarSrinivasan, I run elixir